# How do I fix my Python sudoku solver bug?

Tags: python, debugging, sudoku

***THIS IS FROM MY HOMEWORK***

---

Hello. I had to make a python sudoku solver and this is what I came up with.

http://pastebin.com/JRKaqSed (includes my input and the output I get)

However, when I run it, the first populate call causes the error below. It seems to add the 1 to two cells at the same time.

```
0 5 9 0 0 0 4 8 3 #Current row being tested
To Add, 1 #Number to add
0 5 #Row, Column
0 5 9 0 1 1 4 8 3 #Row it outputs
```

I can't figure out why it is doing that. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

EDIT:

I found the bug. I was only generating the rowSet at the start of each row and therefore it didn't know if a number had already been used.

However, my code still doesn't finish the sudoku grid

Comment: I found the bug. But my code doesn't get to a finished grid :/

Comment: You should probably post the solution to your problem as an answer for future users.

Answer (score 3):

I can't replicate the error you get, but there's a problem with how you read in the sudoku grid.

```
0 5 9 0 0 0 4 8 3
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2
0 1 0 0 2 8 0 0 0
0 9 8 0 7 4 0 2 0
0 4 0 0 8 0 0 3 0
0 7 0 6 3 0 5 4 0
0 0 0 1 6 0 0 5 0
6 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
7 3 5 0 0 0 8 6 0
```

Reading in this file the way you do:

```
fi = open("sudoku.txt", "r")
inFile = fi.read()
grid = [list(i) for i in inFile.split("\n")]
```

This creates a grid that's a list of lists, but not the one you expect. For example, here's the first line:

`['0', ' ', '5', ' ', '9', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', '0', ' ', '4', ' ', '8', ' ', '3']`

Instead of reading the file into a string and splitting it on the newline, you can loop through the open file object and split each line in the split on the space.

```
fi = open("sudoku.txt", "r")
grid = []
for line in fi:
    grid.append([int(i) for i in line.split(" ")])
```

So I think your problem was related to the spaces still being present in your grid, because after fixing this (and another problem regarding oldGrid somewhere), it solves the sudoku.

Comment: Sorry, I gave the incorrect input. The input I actually use is a non-space separated version of that.

Also: I have found the bug, but that you for your response.
I have also updated my paste in pastebin to the correct input

http://pastebin.com/JRKaqSed

Comment: @AceFire6 So does it work now? Because reading in the grid and printing it correctly were the only issues I had so far. Obviously I didn't verify the solution, but it seemed to work just fine

Comment: No, it doesn't fully solve the grid. It gets to this: pastebin.com/8sgUzXVN and then it stops filling in new grid positions

Comment: Odd, my version works just fine, I've posted the code + command line output here: https://gist.github.com/ivoflipse/5575983

Comment: The grid is invalid though. In sudoku you can't have a number appearing in the same row or column more than once. I have updated my code to fix the bug which causes the incorrect output you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug. I was only generating the rowSet at the start of each row and therefore it didn't know if a number had already been used, which was causing the problem.

Here is the corrected code:
http://pastebin.com/JRKaqSed

It still doesn't output the fully finished sudoku grid though.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider trying several partially solved sudoku puzzles as a test, to figure out what kind of cases its not dealing with correctly. Or consider writing unit tests for the functions that you think check for certain conditions.